# Docker WAN Emulator

Tags: docker, emulation, wan

I have a program running each in one docker container and they communicate with each other. Because the container are running on mostly one machine, I want to emulate a WAN for these containers to simulate packet loss, latency, delay, etc.
Is there a lightweight solution for this?

I have looked up WANem but it seems I need to put that in an extra virtual machine and put that between the communication of the docker containers. What would be ideal is a program running in each docker container which emulates latency, packet loss, etc.

Comment: maybe this might help? although it doesn't contain much details, https://github.com/bprodoehl/docker-wan-emulator

Comment: You may use [Pumba](https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba) that works on even single machine, also with compose deployment files to model deployment and networks between containers.